# How to reset value on click in React Native animated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have a progress bar screen inside navigation that I need to be reset every time user clicks on that specific route. Now it only plays animation when I go to that route for the first time. My question is: how to reset barWidth so that animation would play every time user clicks on specific route?

What have I tried?

I thought that the problem is that the component is not re-rendering and thats why value is not resetting, but it looks like the problem is that the width of the bar doesn't reset when user clicks on the screen after animation plays.

At first I've tried using useRef hook and later changed to simply setting the animated value to 0, but in both cases the bar's width didn't reset.

Code:

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const SettingsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  return (
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={style.barContainer}
      data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
      keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={() => (
        <ProgressBar isFocused={isFocused} navigation={navigation} />
      )}
    ></FlatList>
  );
};

const ProgressBar = ({ navigation, isFocused }) => {
  //const barWidth = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const barWidth = new Animated.Value(0);

  console.log(barWidth);

  const finalWidth = width / 2;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      Animated.spring(barWidth, {
        toValue: finalWidth,
        bounciness: 10,
        speed: 2,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    });

    return listener;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={style.contentContainer}>
      <Animated.View style={[style.progressBar, { width: barWidth }]} />
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 30,
  },
  barContainer: {
    padding: 30,
  },
  progressBar: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    width: width / 2,
    height: 15,
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The addListener function is Deprecated. try to use addEventListener instead.
also, why is it inside a const listener with the return listener?
as i see it you can write the useEffect like that:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addEventListener("focus", () => {
      Animated.spring(barWidth, {
        toValue: finalWidth,
        bounciness: 10,
        speed: 2,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    });

  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: addListener function is working just fine, I'm using "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13".